# Puzzling Theory of Equations statement

Tags: complex-numbers

In Uspensky's *Theory of Equations* he  defines a complex number as $(a,b)$, then he states

$$(2,\sqrt{12}) = \left(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{7+ 4\sqrt{3}}\;+\;\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{7- 4\sqrt{3}}\,,\,2\sqrt{3}\,\right)$$

since

$$2 = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{7+ 4\sqrt{3}}\;+\;\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{7- 4\sqrt{3}} $$

I assume there's some "a priori" way of getting to this odd expression of $2$. Where is this from?

Comment: Hint: Square it. Nothing can kill a square root except squaring.

Comment: These things often don't have any "a priori" way of reaching to. It depends on the context where it arises. According the context, you need to manipulate the variables so that you arrive at your desired form.

Comment: @Trebor Substitution can also kill a square root :D

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to find a more general form of your statement and ended up generalizing it a bit more than I expected:

$$n=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{(n^2+k)- 2n\sqrt{k}} + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{(n^2+k)+ 2n\sqrt{k}}$$

for $0 \le k \le n^2$.

This can be proven, as others have suggested, by doubling and then squaring both sides:

$$\begin{align}
2n &= \sqrt{(n^2+k)- 2n\sqrt{k}} + \sqrt{(n^2+k)+ 2n\sqrt{k}} \\
4n^2 &= \left[ (n^2+k)- 2n\sqrt{k} \right] + \left[ (n^2+k)+ 2n\sqrt{k} \right] + 2 \sqrt{(n^2+k)^2 - 4n^2k}\\
&= 2(n^2+k) + 2 \sqrt{(n^2-k)^2}\\
&= 4n^2
\end{align}$$

Thus there are numerous such representations that can be found for any natural number. As an example, if $\,n=3$, we have

$$\begin{align}
3 &= \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\strut 9} + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\strut 9} & (k=0)\\
\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\strut 10 - 6}  + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\strut 10 + 6} & (k=1)\\
\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{11 - 6\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{11 + 6\sqrt{2}} & (k=2)\\
\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{12 - 6\sqrt{3}} + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{12 + 6\sqrt{3}} & (k=3)\\
\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\strut 13 - 12} + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\strut 13 + 12} & (k=4)\\
\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{14 - 6\sqrt{5}} + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{14 + 6\sqrt{5}} & (k=5)\\
\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{15 - 6\sqrt{6}} + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{15 + 6\sqrt{6}} & (k=6)\\
\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{16 - 6\sqrt{7}} + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{16 + 6\sqrt{7}} & (k=7)\\
\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{17 - 6\sqrt{8}} + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{17 + 6\sqrt{8}} & (k=8)\\
\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\strut 18 - 18} + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\strut 18 + 18} & (k=9)\\
\end{align}$$

The representation of $\,2\,$ in your question uses $\,k=3$.

There's also

$$n=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{(n^2+k)+ 2n\sqrt{k}} - \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{(n^2+k)- 2n\sqrt{k}}$$

for $k \ge n^2$, and both formulas will work with $k < 0$ if you allow for imaginary roots.

Comment: Very interesting, but it still seems out of thin air. How did you come by this? What's the bigger pattern?

Comment: I don't know whether there is a bigger underlying pattern, but in any event I didn't use one. I just noted that when squaring the expression, the result had the form $2\alpha + 2\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}$, which seemed to indicate the possibility of multiple solutions as well as solutions for values other than $2$. After finding a couple of solutions for $3$ and $4$ the pattern appeared, and then it was quickly obvious that $\alpha$ could be any natural (or even real) number.

Answer (score 1):

These things often don't have any "a priori" way of reaching to. It depends on the context where it arises. According the context, you need to manipulate the variables so that you arrive at your desired form. However, you can check easily that it's true.

$$y=\sqrt{7+ 4\sqrt{3}}\;+\;\sqrt{7- 4\sqrt{3}}$$
gives
$$y^2=7+ 4\sqrt{3}+7- 4\sqrt{3}+2\sqrt{49-48}=16$$
which gives
$$y=4$$

Comment: y=4 in your solution. But there is a 1/2 in front in the real question, so the answer is correct

Comment: @Nurator thanks for pointing it out. It was a stupid mistake :|